# How to use random not to change the text but to create a new item?

Tags: python

I want to use random to create a new number but leave the ones already generated the same!

Like this:

```
import simplegui
import random

item_pos = [150, 0]
next_one = '7'

def random_number():
    global next_one, item_pos
    if item_pos[1] >= 10:
        next_one = (random.choice(['3', '7', '9', '5']))
        item_pos[0] = random.randrange(50, 250)

def draw(canvas):
    timer.start()
    canvas.draw_text(next_one, item_pos, 15, 'Red')        

def mov():
    item_pos[1] += 1

frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 500)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
timer = simplegui.create_timer(100, mov)
frame.add_button("Random", random_number, 100)

frame.start()
```

When the number is coming down, if you click random I want the code to generate a different number and location but leave the previous numbers on their own, just like tetris for example.

other attempt:

```
import simplegui
import random

item_pos = [150, 0]
next_one = ['bread']
n = 0
next_one1 = '0'
item_pos1 = [150, 0]

def random_number():
    global next_one
    if item_pos[1] >= 10:
        next_one.append(random.choice(['3', '7', '9', '5']))
    return next_one

def random_pos():
    item_pos = random.randrange(50, 250)
    return item_pos

def random_new():
    item_pos1 = [random_pos(), 0]
    next_one1 = random.choice(next_one)
    return item_pos1, next_one1

def draw(canvas):
    global n
    timer.start()
    canvas.draw_text(next_one[n], item_pos, 15, 'Red')        
    canvas.draw_text(next_one1, item_pos1, 15, 'green')

def mov():
    item_pos[1] += 1

def other():
    global n
    random_number()
    n += 1


frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 500)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
timer = simplegui.create_timer(100, mov)
frame.add_button("Start", other, 100)
frame.add_button("Outro", random_new, 100)

random_number()
frame.start()
```

Using lists this time and still nothing

Comment: I tried making a new list and appending the random number to that new list and then printing out to a new random position, but still nothing

Comment: that seems like a great start! Why don't you update your code with that attempt? What exactly went wrong with it?

Comment: Okay, a couple of things. First, your draw code should draw _everything_ every tick, not just one thing. So rather than having a global `n`, why don't you try storing all your values in a list and drawing them all every time?

Comment: second, you're storing all your generated values in a list, but not their positions. Rather than thinking of these things in terms of "next one" and "item position", why don't you think about it as a list of items, where each item has a numeric value and a position.

Comment: So you are saying just to store the position? For example in tetris only came on piece at a time now imagine a tetris where there a few pieces on game but you only can control the first and they all have different positions originated randomly, do you think that can be accomplished only by storing the positions?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, no. I'm saying store both the position of the item _and_ the content of the item (the randomly-generated number) in lists. Right now, you're storing the content in a list but you have only two positions, not a list of positions.

Comment: okay i get it! Just one more question do you think it's easier to use a dictionary instead of a list? The key being the item(number) and the value being the position of that item?

Comment: That's not so much a question of easier or harder; the two options are functionally different. Think what would happen if you randomly generate two of the same number.